# Backbone Tree and Demand Graph

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, integer-programming, algebraic-graph-theory

We defined the terms *Backbone Tree* and *Demand Graph*, however I don't remember how those terms are defined and I don't know how to construct them.

Using those structures, one can construct the *Network Matrix* (I guess kind of a incidence matrix?), which is [totally unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity/wiki/Unimodular_matrix).
Actually, we defined Backbone Tree and Demand Graph to prove total unimodularity of matrices.

Unfortunately, I am not able to find those terms anywhere but in my lecture notes, so maybe they're commonly known under an other name?
Fortunately, I remember the concept was quite simple, however I forgot it :(